# Export DXL to Richtext item causes 64k errors

Tags: java, lotus-notes, richtext

I have a Java agent that exports design elements to documents in a separate database (one document per element). If elements are complex and the produced DXL becomes bigger my export works but I get errors when opening the document with my form:

[image: 64k error]

This my code (excerpt):

```
DxlExporter exporter = session.createDxlExporter();
RichTextItem dxl = designDoc.createRichTextItem(DesignElement.ITEM_DXLOUTPUT);

dxl.appendText(exporter.exportDxl(doc));
dxl.setSaveToDisk(true);
dxl.compact();
designDoc.save();
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the field in the Form to store contents as MIME and used computeWithForm, would that resolve the problem by breaking the content up?

Comment: Well in fact that seems to solve the problem - can it be that easy?

Comment: Just tested it: it wasn't the MIME setting but the computeWithForm